# Error while running '$ python CommonModules/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, settings

i am new to django. I am deploying my simple web application on heroku server via github. But when i deploy it, my build going to fail and it show this error on heroku logs:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.8.3
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting appdirs==1.4.4
         Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
       Collecting asgiref==3.2.10
         Downloading asgiref-3.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting distlib==0.3.1
         Downloading distlib-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (335 kB)
       Collecting Django==3.0.8
         Downloading Django-3.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
       Collecting django-filter==2.3.0
         Downloading django_filter-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
       Collecting filelock==3.0.12
         Downloading filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4
         Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
       Collecting Pillow==7.2.0
         Downloading Pillow-7.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
       Collecting pytz==2020.1
         Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
       Collecting six==1.15.0
         Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
       Collecting sqlparse==0.3.1
         Downloading sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
       Collecting virtualenv==20.0.26
         Downloading virtualenv-20.0.26-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 MB)
       Collecting virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.6
         Downloading virtualenvwrapper-win-1.2.6.tar.gz (21 kB)
       Collecting whitenoise==5.1.0
         Downloading whitenoise-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Building wheels for collected packages: virtualenvwrapper-win
         Building wheel for virtualenvwrapper-win (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for virtualenvwrapper-win (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for virtualenvwrapper-win: filename=virtualenvwrapper_win-1.2.6-py3-none-any.whl size=18609 sha256=2894b9f0d8294f17c34d3498acb2ec9baba93dd1039a36a8e44c1252d8d2bb41
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-lqj2a4ec/wheels/66/25/f7/f4b3539b1cc86289c4e24e637c09a39f8f2ab6de61928f0be1
       Successfully built virtualenvwrapper-win
       Installing collected packages: appdirs, asgiref, distlib, pytz, sqlparse, Django, django-filter, filelock, gunicorn, Pillow, six, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper-win, whitenoise
       Successfully installed Django-3.0.8 Pillow-7.2.0 appdirs-1.4.4 asgiref-3.2.10 distlib-0.3.1 django-filter-2.3.0 filelock-3.0.12 gunicorn-20.0.4 pytz-2020.1 six-1.15.0 sqlparse-0.3.1 virtualenv-20.0.26 virtualenvwrapper-win-1.2.6 whitenoise-5.1.0
-----> $ python CommonModules/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
           import psycopg2 as Database
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "CommonModules/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
           main()
         File "CommonModules/manage.py", line 17, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
           django.setup()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
           apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
           app_config.import_models()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
           self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
           from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
           class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in __new__
           new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
           value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
           self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
           return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
           backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
           return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
           raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
       django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
 !     Error while running '$ python CommonModules/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

My settings.py file in django project is:

```
"""
Django settings for common project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '***************************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['common-module.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'user'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'common.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'common.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'common',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'****',
        'HOST':'localhost'
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

My requirements.txt file:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.2.10
distlib==0.3.1
Django==3.0.8
django-filter==2.3.0
filelock==3.0.12
gunicorn==20.0.4
Pillow==7.2.0
psycopg2==2.8.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
virtualenv==20.0.26
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.6
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

Can anyone told me where i am doing wrong. And the solution to successfully deploy this app on heroku.

Comment: looks like some heroku issue. psycopg2 is not installed, despite that you've defined it in your requirements. I'd search if there are any similar issues with psycopg2 in heroku.

Comment: And i am getting error of collectstatic --noinput also.

Comment: Two things that come to my mind: 

- you only need one of `psycopg2` or `psycopg2-binary` (we're always using the latter)

- since Heroku doesn't even try to install `psycopg2` that actually looks like the last changes to `requirements.txt` are not committed and on master.


the [buildpack script is actually quite straightforward in what it does](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/181e3395f909d4216b33e2f801c5fe3f4a720249/bin/steps/pip-install#L51)